# Genymotion displaying distorced graphics

Tags: genymotion

I'm trying to use Genymotion but my displays keep seeing distorced, on all apps and mobile versions.

The issue can be seen on this image:

[issue on genymotion graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTlp9.png)

Comment: Can you please add minimal complete viable code?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your GPU does not meet Genymotion minimal requirements. See https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/3.1/01_Get_started/011_Requirements.html#hardware